# converting "drawing in a table" functionality - from jQuery to pure JS

Tags: javascript, html

I found an example of easy drawing in a table on css-tricks website. With jQuery it looks like this:

```
$("#drawing-table").delegate("td", "mousedown", function() {
        mouseDownState = true;
        $el = $(this);
        if (eraseState) {
            $el.removeAttr("style");
        } else {
            $el.css("background", curColor);
        }
    }).delegate("td", "mouseenter", function() {
        if (mouseDownState) {
            $el = $(this);
            if (eraseState) {
                $el.removeAttr("style");
            } else {

                // DRAWING ACTION
                $el.css("background", curColor);
            }
        }
    });
    $("html").bind("mouseup", function() {
        mouseDownState = false;
    });
```

But I need the same witout using jQuery. So I tried to convert it to pure JS. But now I doesn't work as expected. Here what I got:

```
theTable = document.getElementById("drawing-table");

theTable.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
        mouseDownState = true;
        el = e.target;
        if (eraseState) {
            el.removeAttribute("style");
        }
        else {
            el.style.backgroundColor = curColor;
        }
    }
});

theTable.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
        if (mouseDownState) {
            el = e.target;

            if (eraseState) {
                 el.removeAttribute("style");
            }
            else {
                el.style.backgroundColor = curColor;
            }
        }
    }
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    mouseDownState = false;
});
```

The script should change the color of cells when I hold the left button of a mouse and move the cursor over the cells I want to color (like in Paint). but it only colors the cell I click on.
I think the problem is because in jQuery version **mouseenter** event listener goes right after **mousedown** event listener. But I don't know how to put one event listener after another.

The original code is taken from https://css-tricks.com/examples/DrawingTable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use "onmouseover" instead of "mouseenter" listener in your code.

```
theTable.onmouseover = function(e){
        if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
            if (mouseDownState) {
                el = e.target;

                if (eraseState) {
                    el.removeAttribute("style");
                }
                else {
                    el.style.backgroundColor = curColor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcom to so. When writing answers, it is a good idea to explain your answer. Your answer is not bad, but maybe say why they should use `onmouseover`

Comment: Yes makes sense. Thanks for the info. 

Explanation: 

The "onmouseover" event fires when the user moves the mouse over a particular element.
As we are already setting the flag "mouseDownState" on "mousedown" event when user click on table, then "onmouseover" is just checking if "mouseDownState" is true and cursor is over the element which gives us what we want i.e. "click-and-drag drawing feature"

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are only triggering events when the mouse enters the *table*. The jQuery code appears to trigger whenever the mouse enters a table *cell*. Mouseenter events only fire once, when the mouse enters the element. It does not repeatedly fire as you move the mouse around the element. Try attaching handlers to all of the cells in the table